# How to pass a parent property by reference instead of by value through an @Input decorator to a child component?

Tags: angular

If a parent component pass a property to a child component through `@Input` decorator, it's passed by value, not by reference. If inside the child component I want to change the parent's property passed by `@Input`, I have to emit the new value through an `@Output` decorator, which we'll be captured by the parent component and assigned to the parent's property.

Is it possible to pass a property through an `@Input` decorator by reference in Angular 2?

Regards,

Bernardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass an `object` to the `@Input`. That will pass it as a reference.

If you change one of the properties on the object it will update referenced data.

example:

```
{name:'Joe'}
```

If the child updates the `name` property it will be seen by the parent.